# Simplifying ln to solve L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to solve these this problem with L'Hôpital's rule but I'm a bit confused as to how to simplify ln to get it into an indeterminate form where I can take the derivative.
$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow 0.5^{-}}\left[(2 x-1)^{4} \ln (1-2 x)\right]
$$

Comment: What do you mean by "simplify ln to get it into an indeterminate form"? The second one is already in the form $0/0$.

Comment: @Karl I don't know how I missed that haha thank you! For the first one, I'm just trying to get it in a form 0/0 or infinity/infinity

Comment: How about $\lim_\limits{x\to \frac 12^-} \frac{\ln(1-2x)}{(2x-1)^{-4}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it as

$$\frac{\ln(1-2x)}{(2x-1)^{-4}}$$

This is an $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form. Differentiating the top and the bottom (by the chain rule for example), we get
$$\frac{-2(1-2x)^{-1}}{-8(2x-1)^{-5}}=\frac{1}{4}\frac{(2x-1)^5}{1-2x}=-\frac{1}{4}(2x-1)^4$$

Now $\lim_{x\to 0.5^{-}}-\frac{1}{4}(2x-1)^4=\boxed{0}$.

Answer (score 0):

That is an indeterminate form :D

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \ln(1-2x) = \ln(1) = 0$$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \sin(4x) = \sin(0) = 0$$

Keep going!

Comment: thank you! I didn't realize the second one was already an indeterminate form

Answer (score 0):

Oof, someone already answered, but I like my solution better :P

When you're stuck on problems like these, try a simple substitution!

Let $y=2x-1 \implies x = \frac {y+1}{2}$.

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0.5^{-}}(2 x-1)^{4} \ln (1-2 x)$

$= \lim\limits_{y\to 0^{-}}y^4\cdot\ln(-y)$

$= \lim\limits_{y\to 0^{-}}\frac{\ln(-y)}{\frac{1}{y^4}}$

Stop! Put your hands in the air!

$= \lim\limits_{y\to 0^{-}} \frac{-1/-y}{-4/y^5}$

$= \lim\limits_{y\to 0^{-}} \frac{-1/y}{4/y^5}$

$= \lim\limits_{y\to 0^{-}} \frac{-y^4}{4}$

$= 0$.

Comment: This is essentially my solution

Comment: I like using substitutions.

Comment: Adam, I can tell

Comment: Also, it says "simplifying ln to solve L'H rule" :D